# Can't access the router management of TP-LINK TL-WR842ND after settingit as an access point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

I disabled DHCP on a TP-LINK TL-WR842ND and connected it LAN-to-LAN to my base router in order to set it as wireless access point for wireless devices.

The TP-LINK received an IP address from the base router, let's say this IP address is 10.0.0.20. I would like to access the web management GUI of TP-LINK so I typed 10.0.0.20 to my web browser hoping that it will show me the TP-LINK page.

Unfortunately I can't access the management web page and I don't know how.

Why might I be unable to access it? It has the right IP address and works as an access point correctly.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

TP-Link needs to be itself configured for the IP address it was assigned, i.e. in Network > LAN submenu set 10.0.0.20 as the address.

## Long answer

(Disclaimer: I am not a network professional, please excuse/correct improperly used terms.)

I ran into the same situation, and the problem I had was a mess of the address setup initially: main router as 192.168.1.1, the TP-Link as 192.168.0.1 router+AP, and I needed the main router to become the 192.168.0.1 and TP-Link working as just the AP while still being able to access TP-Link's administration.

The goal to achieve is to have the TP-Link as AP on the same network segment but with different address than the main router and outside its DHCP range (e.g. main = 192.168.1.1 with DHCP 1.100-1.199, TP-Link AP = 192.168.1.2), plus properly configured itself.

### Setup

```
WAN <---> main router <---> TP-Link router 
            ^                  ^    
            |                  |
            v                  v
          computer           computer
```

The main router has DHCP enabled and you can access its administration. On TP-Link, the cable to main router is in LAN port, not in the WAN port.  The computer (e.g. notebook) is connected via Ethernet i.e. wired, not wireless.

### Procedure

1. Note or decide on the main router's IP and DHCP address range (e.g. 192.168.1.1 and 1.100-1.199), based on your goal.
2. In TP-Link's admin pages, select *Network > LAN* submenu, and provide an address for the TP-Link according to the goal, e.g. 192.168.1.2 .  Reboot.  Check that you can connect to the TP-Link administration; if you changed it's segment part of the address, you may first need to reconfigure the static address of the computer's network connection.
3. Switch off DHCP on TP-Link (menu *DHCP > DHCP Settings:* DHCP Server: disable).  Reboot.  (Attempt to access it's administration may fail now. Keep going.)
4. (if needed) Reconfigure main router to have IP address and DHCP range according to the goal (e.g. 192.168.1.1 and 1.100-1.199). Reboot.
5. (optional) Set the static address of TP-Link in main router's config to the one entered in step 2.  Switch off firewall etc. in TP-Link's config.

At this point, you should be able to access main router (on 192.168.1.1) as well as TP-Link (on 192.168.1.2, acting as AP only), and devices connected by WiFi via the AP should get correct addresses from main router's DHCP range.

### Debugging

If a device's administration is not accessible, it can be because of these reasons:

- Conflicting network segment / IP address configuration (e.g. main 192.168.1.1, TP-Link 192.168.2.1) -- disconnect the cable between the two devices and connect your computer directly to the one you need to configure, as shown in Setup; once problem is solved, reconnect again.
- Misconfigured / disabled DHCP of the device, thus the notebook cannot get it's IP address and communicate -- if you know the IP / segment of the device, set the notebook's network connection address as "static" on the same segment (e.g. 192.168.1.111 for a main on 192.168.1.1)

If any of the above does not help, or if you cannot determine the device's segment / IP address, then factory reset of the device will configure it to a known default IP.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me.
What I ended up doing is resetting it to factory settings and keeping DHCP open, but with a different range.

If you don't mind having two routers, you can also set up WR842ND as a "Dyanmic Connection", and plug the router into the WR842ND's WAN connection.
This way, you have two separate domains.
Your router can be on 10.0.0.0/8, and your WR842ND can be on 192.168.0.0/8 .

Answer (score 0):

The WR842 is supported by the DD-WRT custom firmware. After installing that, you can use [the wiki instructions](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point) to setup an access point, most importantly disabling the DHCP and configuring the operating mode as 'router'.

I also had to assign an IP (by MAC address, the IP matching the one specified in the WR842 GUI) to the WR842 in my *actual* router.

**Notes:**

- The router will have 2 or 3 MAC addresses (`WAN`, `LAN` and `Wireless`). The `LAN` one is the one that should be assigned a static IP in the main router.